Why web scraping TaskerNet stops working after a few seconds in Python?
I am working on a script to download TaskerNet data.
The code
import requests
import json
def taskernet(page_token=None):
   base_url = "https://taskernet.com/_ah/api/datashare/v1/shares/public"
   if page_token:
     request = requests.get(base_url+"?a=0&tags=&pageToken={page_token}")
   else:
     request = requests.get(base_url)
    # print(request.content)
   data = json.loads(request.content)
   shares = data["shares"]
   for share in shares:
      print(share['url'])
   page_token_b = data["pageToken"]
   taskernet(page_token_b)
   
 
taskernet()

returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cat/Documents/TaskerNet/script.py", line 17, in <module>
    taskernet()
  File "/home/cat/Documents/TaskerNet/script.py", line 15, in taskernet
    taskernet(page_token_b)
  File "/home/cat/Documents/TaskerNet/script.py", line 11, in taskernet
    shares = data["shares"]
             ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'shares'
cat@Ubuntu:~/Documents/TaskerNet$ 


I tried asking AI, but it wanted me to fix things that are not broken.
I tried searching for errors, nothing.

To print all shares URL you can use normal iteration instead recursion (and check if shares key is inside data, if not, break from loop):
import requests

base_url = "https://taskernet.com/_ah/api/datashare/v1/shares/public"

current_url = base_url
while True:
    data = requests.get(current_url).json()

    if "shares" not in data:
        break

    for s in data["shares"]:
        print(s["url"])

    current_url = base_url + f"?a=0&tags=&pageToken={data.get('pageToken', '')}"

Prints:

...

https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8kp%2FjDVAFZcITqL4EnthwjhxvGvjzOpY90XoYZwHtu8gNQXySrB001t%2BP7Q53z8Ypt1wK6Y&id=Project%3ATarefas+De+Teste
https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8lozrpBt%2FkXbY0d6Qk71PGyqFHfHS9Z6X7MAJVGLxRVmMrvXdULUMUhzgDfrnnZ&id=Project%3AUninstall+Google
https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8nx2PJX2RFzQe6PgJZfwltHxeRYzAMzcnS1vjhUa8whveBocRX%2BYq9h3jXNlc8ijwGdFgn4Oj4%3D&id=Task%3AStake
https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8leVkAV644E8XFbqVJU82sJLucctSwmlbJe3wQP567zloMqJrtfaivFoEGKf9U%3D&id=Profile%3AAuto+Connect+Hot+Spot

